# Making a list out of the contents from a parsed file

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to parse a log file for a specific deliminator ("##"). Once parsed I get the contents of each line. I then split the line using .split(" ") which gives me the string I am looking for in each line. I would like to take each line and put it into a list. Below is how I have it coded right now.

```
LNsearch = "##"   
old = open(file)
with old as f
    for line in f:
        if LNsearch in line:
            LNfinder = line.split(" ")[1].replace('\n','')
            print(LNfinder)

results:

str1
str2
str3
str4
...
```

I am looking to get ['str1','str2','str3','str4','...']

Thanks,

Comment: You would initialize the list outside the loop `l = []` and then inside the loop you would append your results `l.append(LNfinder)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am getting a pyramid with my data. I think it is because of the for loop. I get str1 in the list then str2 gets appended and so on. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the idea that Patrick Haugh mentioned in the comments.

I used a file named test.txt with content of:

```
## str1
## str2 X

## str3 X
## str4 X
```

The code below opens and reads test.txt.
The for loop parses each line and searchs for "##" and " " in the line.
If found, appends the split item at index 1 to the list named lst, with \n removed.
The list named lst is finally print at the end.

```
# Test file to read.
file = 'test.txt'

LNsearch = "##"

with open(file) as f:
    # Prepare list to collect wanted strings.
    lst = []

    for line in f:

        # Require "##" in line and " " in line to be valid.
        if LNsearch in line and " " in line:

            # Get 2nd substring and ensure no \n.
            LNfinder = line.split(" ")[1].replace('\n','')

            # This appends to the list named lst.
            lst.append(LNfinder)

    # Print final list.
    print('lst:', lst)
```

Output is:

```
lst: ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. It really helped me with what I was missing.